# How to build a custom tan function that goes through specified points

Tags: trigonometry

**Intro**
I often need trigonometric functions while programming, but I'm not always able to get what I want — especially when dealing with $tan$. Every time I need it, I spend hours trying to figure out the function.

**Request**
What I really need is a function like the one in this graph, where `0 < x < 1` and `fn(0.5) = 0.5`, with a variable *slope* (curves more **or** less accentuated)

[image: Tangent function graph]

**Current work**
I was able to plot that on Grapher.app with this equation, but it's manually tweaked to hit those points: $y={\tan(2.78x-1.38)\over\pi^2}+0.5$

Every time I need to change the *slope*, that function requires infinite tweaking to make the ends match [0,0] and [1,1]

**Notes**
It doesn't have to be a $tan$, just anything that resembles that graph. Even pointing me to *anything that would help me understand* how to *warp* trig functions to touch my points would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look at $y=\tanh mx / \tanh m$ for starters. Then find the inverse function to get the shape right. After that, a linear change of coordinates should do it. You see?

This gives $y = \frac12[1+\frac1m \tanh^{-1}((2x-1)\tanh m)]$. Varying $m$ will change the slope at the center point $(1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: Awesome! That was it. [Graph with multiple values of $m$](http://i.imgur.com/cN2cJfF.png) to show what I wanted. [For fellow developers,](http://phpjs.org/functions/atanh/) $\tanh^{-1}$ is the same as $atanh$ — I had to do a bit of research.

Comment: You can also see then that the slope at $x=\frac12$ is $\frac{\tanh m}{m}$, which may be useful. Note this is a value between $0$ and $1$, as your graphs suggest.

Answer (score 2):

The general function is of the form:

$$f(x) = A\tan(B(x-C))+D$$

**The "center point"**: This function goes through the center point $(C, D)$. In your case you want $C=\dfrac{1}{2}, D=\dfrac{1}{2}$.

**The "diagonal points"**: Tangent is an odd function, meaning this "shifted" version has the property that if $t>0$, $f(C+t) = -f(C-t)$. The values of these depend on the value of $A$, the "vertical stretchyness" of the graph. If you plug in $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4B}+C$ then $f(x) = A+D$. Since you want to go through $(1,1)$ you need

$$A+D=1 \ \ \text{  and  } \ \ \dfrac{\pi}{4B}+C=1$$

Since $C,D=\frac{1}{2}$ this means $B$ must be $B=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $A=\dfrac{1}{2}$. By symmetry, it will also pass through $(0,0)$.

$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\left(x-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\right) + \dfrac{1}{2}$$

is the desired function for your above graph.

Comment: That function doesn't offer a parameter for a variable slope, though